# Regex to strip line break at the end of line

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Why this regex does not strip "\n" from the end of line, but strips it in the middle? "\n" should be disallowed at any position.

Regex: `"^[\w ]*$"`

Works:

- "\nabc"
- "a\nb"

Does not work:

- "\n"
- "abc\n"

Comment: Just that regex alone won't "strip" anything.  Which regex tool/language are you using?

Comment: @SebastianProske  "\n" should be disallowed at any position.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Python 3.7

Comment: It is supposed to match whatever comes after beginning of line (probably). So `^` asserts right after `\n`. It means your regex starts to match from there or beginning of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in non-multiline mode, the `$` allows a single trailing linebreak to follow. That is stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of
>   the string

To avoid, you can add a lookahead to check that no newline follow, like

```
^[\w ]*$(?!\n)
```